# sum hours and minutes in 2 tables and display results in HH:MM

Tags: sqlite

i have 2 tables, First table is master table having columns in left in  HH:MM format taking info from columns in right which are in  hh and mm formats

```
ACType   A     B        C      Ahr    Amin     Bhr    Bmin     Chr      Cmin

A320   12:34 85:45    07:23     12      34      85     45      7         23
B777   20:00 30:00    10:00     20      0       30     0      10         0
```

Second table has  columns in hh and mm format

```
ACType       Bhr   Bmin      Chr      Cmin

A320          10       20     46       31
```

How can I get final result:

```
ACType    A    B    C     Ahr     Amin   Bhr     Bmin     Chr    Cmin

A320  12:34  96:05 53:54  12       34     95      65       53      54
B777  20:00  30:00 10:00  20       0      30      0        10      0
```

Comment: How do the rows in the two tables correlate? They don't have anything in common to join them on.

Comment: corrected..thnx

Comment: That's not corrected. Your example rows still don't have anything in common to know what to join on, unless you want to do a cross join where each row in the first table is joined to every row in the second table in turn. The second table should ideally have a foreign key that references a key in the first table so you can tell which rows match up with which.

Comment: Apologies Shawn..ACType is the foreign key..thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
   first.ACType,
   first.A,
   (
     x.Bhr + x.Bmin / 60
   )
   || ':' || printf(" % 02d", x.Bmin % 60) AS B,
   (
     x.Chr + x.Cmin / 60
   )
   || ':' || printf(" % 02d", x.Cmin % 60) AS C,
   first.Ahr,
   first.Amin,
   x.Bhr,
   x.Bmin,
   x.Chr,
   x.Cmin
FROM
   first
   LEFT JOIN
     (
        SELECT
           ACType,
           SUM(Bhr) AS Bhr,
           SUM(Bmin)AS Bmin,
           SUM(Chr) AS Chr,
           SUM(Cmin) AS Cmin
        FROM
           (
              SELECT
                 ACType,
                 Bhr,
                 Bmin,
                 Chr,
                 Cmin
              FROM
                 first
              UNION ALL
              SELECT
                 ACType,
                 Bhr,
                 Bmin,
                 Chr,
                 Cmin
              FROM
                 SECOND
           )
        GROUP BY
           ACType
     )
     AS x
WHERE
   first.ACType = x.ACType
```

Answer (score -2):

select null as A, *
from second_table